# Macbook won't boot

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I have a Macbook pro 13" that won't boot up. I searched for solutions online and the issue seemed battery related to me. I opened the back panel of my Mac and took out the RAM and placed it back. After this, the Mac started to work perfectly fine.
However, after a couple of days of usage, the Mac has stopped booting again. Repeating the above process of re-placing the RAM solves the issue but its temporary.

After a day or so, my Mac doesn't even start. When you press the power button, the fan comes on for a spilt second and then goes off.

Any reason why this much be happening or how this can be fixed?!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you test the installed memory. Do it once or twice a day until your Mac freezes up. 
Go here:
http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/03/memtest-mac-ram-test/
Click on Download MemTest now (direct download link)
Run that installer package.
Launch Terminal (Command-Spacebar and type Terminal)
Enter memtest all 2  (Runs tests twice; Change number for more or fewer tests)
This will start the memory test.

Watch for and post any errors here. Errors would be anything that does not return 'OK.' Or an error code(number) other than zero.